# how to compare two c# program in windows 7 in case of running time

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010

I wrote two program with `c#` language in `VS2010` on `windows 7`.

I want to compare them based on the running time, in other words I want to know which one is faster.

Unfortunately their running time duration are in millisecond scale .The problem is when I run them separately once I saw one of them is faster but next when I again repeat running them I see another result I mean faster one change to slower one.

Is there anything in windows which brings two totally equal environment in order to compare time?

Input file for both of them is same and when I use bigger input file time precedes to seconds but even though the problem still remains

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand, can you explain more what you are trying to do? Also if the running times are so close you need a special environment to test it out, does it really matter which one you use?

Comment: yes sir, I did that for university research project.As you like to know the topic is packet classification. We enhance prior algorithm .By the way we implemented new structure and we just want to now which one is faster. Excuse me you are master and you have more knowledge than me based your stack overflow score

Comment: @alex my parser crashed after "I wrote two program"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any "it's too fast to measure" profiling problem can be solved by doing it repeatedly.  Run your test code in a loop that executes it a thousand or a million times.  A billion if you are measuring individual cpu instructions.

That does **not** mean your measurement is representative for the way it is going to run when you only execute it once.  Modern machines are very lousy at doing a job they've never done before, caches are King.  But you'll get a measurement of the *amortized* execution time of the code.  The one that *really* matters when your code needs to deal with real data sets.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to ensure your environment is exactly the same for every time would be to create an image of your test environment and run it as a virtual machine. You can then reload the system with each new test.

However it is possible to measure the runtime in milliseconds, you just need to use the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.aspx) class.

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
// run your test here...
stopWatch.Stop();

TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
```

Alternatively you can just run your tests multiple times and time each and any slight discrepancies would be averaged out.

Comment: I exactly write this code!!! But I have the problem